# How do I initialize an array of vectors?

Tags: arrays, rust

I would like to create an array of vectors:

```
fn main() {
    let v: [Vec<u8>; 10] = [Vec::new(); 10];
}
```

However, the compiler gives me this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<u8>: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:2:28
  |
2 |     let v: [Vec<u8>; 10] = [Vec::new(); 10];
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
  |
  = note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot use the `[expr; N]` initialisation syntax for non-`Copy` types because of Rust’s ownership model—it executes the expression once only, and for non-`Copy` types it cannot just copy the bytes N times, they must be owned in one place only.

You will need to either:

1. Write it out explicitly ten times: `let v: [Vec<u8>; 10] = [vec![], vec![], vec![], vec![], vec![], vec![], vec![], vec![], vec![], vec![]]`, or
2. Use something like a vector instead of the array: `std::iter::repeat(vec![]).take(10).collect::<Vec<_>>()`.

See also:

- [Initialize a large, fixed-size array with non-Copy types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28656387/155423)

Comment: I understand Vec doesnt implement Copy and its not possible because of that but why is that?
After all a Vec is cloneable(or was at least) and most types are so why not use clone internally?

Comment: `Copy` is about a data type being represented precisely by its bytes, so that merely copying the bytes is enough to copy the value. This won't do for `Vec` because the actual data is stored in a heap allocation rich must be uniquely owned. A memory copy of a `Vec` would violate memory safety.

Comment: I have the very same issue handling an array of 256 vectors :(

Comment: @mfirry: writing something out 256 times isn't actually that bad, you know.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan that's debatable. I figured I could initialize it inside a loop or something.

Comment: @mfirry: well you can’t really. Not safely, anyway. But I maintain that writing it out 256 times isn’t actually that bad. Sure, it’s verbose, but will it kill you or is it inherently evil? Nah.

Comment: Nearly a year later now. Surely there's a *good* way to do this by now?

Comment: @Wallacoloo: the situation has not changed, nor are there any concrete plans which would change it. I don’t think I’ve even seen any serious *suggestions* for ways to “improve” it, actually.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan how about now? 4 years later? If writing it out 256 times is allowed, why would there not be some sort of macro that allows you to do that N times...

Comment: There are a few [related crates](https://crates.io/search?q=array+init). [arr_macro](https://crates.io/crates/arr_macro) would expand `arr![vec![]; 3]` to `[vec![], vec![], vec![]]`. [array-init](https://crates.io/crates/array-init) lets `array_init(Vec::new)` produce an array of up to 512 elements. No good solution can exist until const generics stabilise, and that’s still some way off. The array-init approach will then finally be good.

Comment: Note that array_init [expects an argument](https://github.com/Manishearth/array-init/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L91); you can use `array_init(|x| Vec::new())`.

Answer (score 22):

You could use the `Default` trait to initialize the array with default values:

```
let array: [Vec<u8>; 10] = Default::default();
```

See [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20v%3A%20%5BVec%3Cu8%3E%3B%2010%5D%20%3D%20Default%3A%3Adefault()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20v%5B3%5D.push(9)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20%26v%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20i)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D) for a working example.

Comment: This only works for `[Vec<T>; N]` where `N <= 32` because Rust only implements the `Default` trait for `array`s of sizes from 0 to 32 (inclusive).

Answer (score 2):

You can only instantiate arrays in such fashion if the type implements the Copy trait. This trait is only for types that can be copied byte by byte (and since vector points to heap, it can't be implemented).

One answer to this problem is the [array_init](https://docs.rs/array-init/0.1.1/array_init/fn.array_init.html) crate that provides much more general way of initializing arrays in complicated fashion.

```
let multi: [Vec<u8>; 10] = array_init::array_init(|_| vec![0; 24]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use `try_into`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: [Vec<u8>; 10] = vec![Vec::new(); 10].try_into().expect("static");
}
```

I don't know when this has been introduced though.