# Initialize a large, fixed-size array with non-Copy types

Tags: rust

I’m trying to initialize a fixed-size array of some nullable, non-copyable type, like an `Option<Box<Thing>>` for some kind of `Thing`. I’d like to pack two of them into a struct without any extra indirection. I’d like to write something like this:

```
let array: [Option<Box<Thing>>; SIZE] = [None; SIZE];
```

But it doesn’t work because the `[e; n]` syntax requires that `e` implements `Copy`. Of course, I could expand it into `SIZE` `None`s, but that can be unwieldy when `SIZE` is large. I don’t believe this can be done with a macro without an unnatural encoding of `SIZE`. Is there a good way to do it?

Yes, this is easy with `unsafe`; is there a way to do it without `unsafe`?

Comment: specifically for `[Option<Box<T>>; N]` you can use transmute from a `[0; N]`: http://is.gd/CC31YQ

Comment: I wrote an answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925673/how-can-i-initialize-an-array-using-a-function

Answer (score 49):

As of Rust 1.63 (released in August 2022), a cleaner alternative to previously posted answers is possible using [`std::array::from_fn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/array/fn.from_fn.html):

```
const SIZE: usize = 100;
let array: [Option<Box<Thing>>; SIZE] = std::array::from_fn(|_| None);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d78da9292b1df0f252c15482b0090209)

If you need to support older Rust versions, or if you need to initialize a `static`, an alternative approach using an intermediate `const` initializer works as of Rust 1.38 (released in September 2019):

```
const SIZE: usize = 100;
const INIT: Option<Box<Thing>> = None; // helper
// also works with static array
let array: [Option<Box<Thing>>; SIZE] = [INIT; SIZE];
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd428b85fdec548f26e953bd29067887)

Both approaches work with or without the `Box`; examples use `Box` because it was used in the question. Both work for arrays of any size.

The second (older) approach has the limitation that the array item must have a representation that can be evaluated at compile time - a constant, enum variant, empty Vec or String, or a primitive container (enum, tuple) composed of those. `None` or a tuple of numbers will work, but a non-empty `Vec` or `String` won't. The `from_fn()` approach has no such limitation.

Answer (score 31):

You could use the [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait to initialize the array with default values:

```
let array: [Option<Box<Thing>>; SIZE] = Default::default();
```

See [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=49b45bded3aac40cded25ea17b6b9d4f&version=stable&backtrace=0) for a working example.

Note that this will only work for arrays with up to 32 elements, because `Default::default` is only implemented for up to `[T; 32]`. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html#impl-Default-for-%5BT%3B%2032%5D.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if `SIZE` is a generic parameter since that parameter can exceed 32.

Comment: @mallwright Exactly. See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66776497/3497181 for a more recent solution which also works with generic parameters. See also https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=afe2b75bfffc9851acb7ee2f7135e84d

Comment: @rnstlr even the answer you link to fails for me with generic parameters: E0401

> can't use generic parameters from outer function

Comment: @AndrewArnott it's difficult to know what your problem is without code. Best to create an example on https://play.rust-lang.org and link it.

Comment: @rnstlr, here you go:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0a3c3dca825af2179b88b37973c7c9d2

Comment: @MatrixDev Ah I see. We can get around it by defining the `INIT` value as an [associated constant](https://dev-doc.rust-lang.org/beta/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/associated-constants.html):
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=81a6cb09e4b6c9fafd07e9c2dc773c05

Comment: @rnstlr nope, doesn't work. sadly you can't use generics in const.

Comment: @MatrixDev So what doesn't work? With the code in the second playground I posted we can create an array any `Option<T>` initialized with `None`.

Comment: @rnstlr, yeah, I've missed the part about associated constant

Answer (score 29):

As of Rust **1.55.0** (which introduced [`<[T; N]>::map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.map)), the following will work:

```
const SIZE: usize = 100;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct THING { data: i64 }

let array = [(); SIZE].map(|_| Option::<THING>::default());
for x in array {
    println!("x: {:?}", x);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bdc02fb1c023ec4ae0d6c0d60208e47b)

Comment: Using the map method comes with some performance considerations, though. [The documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.map) states: "Unfortunately, usages of this method are currently not always optimized as well as they could be. This mainly concerns large arrays, as mapping over small arrays seem to be optimized just fine. Also note that in debug mode (i.e. without any optimizations), this method can use a lot of stack space (a few times the size of the array or more)."

Comment: @AlejandroGonzález does it refer to the size of the input or output array? the input array is just ZST.

Comment: @SOFe `[T]::map()` is defined to return an array of the same size as the input, so there is only one size to care about.

Comment: Scrap that, it refers to the array length! Honestly, it's a good question I don't know the answer for.

Answer (score 7):

I'm copying [the answer by chris-morgan](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/29ymbx/a_macro_to_fill_a_fixed_length_array/cipruax) and adapting it to match the question better, to follow the recommendation by dbaupp downthread, and to match recent syntax changes:

```
use std::mem;
use std::ptr;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Thing {
    number: usize,
}

macro_rules! make_array {
    ($n:expr, $constructor:expr) => {{
        let mut items: [_; $n] = mem::uninitialized();
        for (i, place) in items.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            ptr::write(place, $constructor(i));
        }
        items
    }}
}

const SIZE: usize = 50;

fn main() {
    let items = unsafe { make_array!(SIZE, |i| Box::new(Some(Thing { number: i }))) };
    println!("{:?}", &items[..]);
}
```

Note the need to use `unsafe` here: The problem is that if the constructor function `panic!`s, this would lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't allow initializing static (global) arrays. The question didn't specify if that's actually needed, but it might be relevant to future readers.

Answer (score 3):

### Go through the heap

If you can create a `Vec` of your type, you can convert it into an array:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Thing;
const SIZE: usize = 100;

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<Option<Thing>> = vec![None; SIZE];
    let v: Box<[Option<Thing>; SIZE]> = match v.into_boxed_slice().try_into() {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(_) => unreachable!(),
    };
    let v: [Option<Thing>; SIZE] = *v;
}
```

In many cases, you actually want to leave it as a `Vec<T>`, `Box<[T]>`, or `Box<[T; N]>` as these types all put the data in the heap. Large arrays tend to be... large... and you don't want all that data on the stack.

See also:

- [What is the use of into_boxed_slice() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39615666/155423)
- [How to get a slice as an array in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25428920/155423)
- [How do I get an owned value out of a `Box`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42264041/155423)

### Keep it simple

Type out all the values:

```
struct Thing;
const SIZE: usize = 5;

fn main() {
    let array: [Option<Box<Thing>>; SIZE] = [None, None, None, None, None];
}
```

You could use [a build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) to generate this code for you. For an example of this, see:

- [How to create a static string at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32956050/155423)

Comment: If n = 256 should I really just copy & paste None 256 times?

Comment: @MatejKormuth depends on a lot of factors, but I don't see anything inherently _wrong_ with it. It's annoying, yes, but simple.

Comment: One such factor: it does work if `SIZE` is generic

Comment: Was looking for Keep it simple advice, my case array is always 20x20=400 elements. Now I'm looking into how to write a macro which would expand into 400 Nones.

Answer (score 2):

On nightly Rust, you can use [inline const](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76001). This is a variant of the answer by @user4815162342, but one that doesn't require you to declare a separate constant and repeat the type:

```rust
#![feature(inline_const)]

let array: [Option<Box<Thing>>; SIZE] = [const { None }; SIZE];
```

Until this is stabilized (hopefully soon), you can also use the [`inline-const`](https://docs.rs/inline-const) crate, but this does require you to repeat the type.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using the [`arrayvec`](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/0.7.0/arrayvec/) crate that generalizes easily to situations other than initializing everything with a fixed value:

```rust
use arrayvec::ArrayVec;

let array = std::iter::repeat(None)
    .take(SIZE)
    .collect::<ArrayVec<Option<Box<Thing>>, SIZE>>()
    .into_inner()
    .unwrap();
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=454405b79e64cdb691ca3ed229df5f4b))

Answer (score 1):

As of Rust 1.63, you can use [from_fn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/fn.from_fn.html):

```rust
let arr: [Option<Box<i64>>; 1000] = std::array::from_fn(|_| None);
assert!(arr.iter().all(|item| item.is_none()));
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bb243e056733d71179c99d1e3f9280b6)

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements all other answers.