# How to repeat a static string at compile time

Tags: rust

I want to create a long `&'static str` made of repeating sequences of chars, e.g. `abcabcabc...`

Is there a way in Rust to do this via an expression, e.g. something like `long_str = 1000 * "abc"` in Python, or do I have to generate it in Python and copy/paste it in the Rust code?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You cannot do such a thing in stable Rust. Your example of `1000 * "abc"` is not run at "compile time" in Python either, as far as I understand Python.

#### Including a file

If it *has* to be static, you could use a [Cargo build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html). This is a bit of Rust code that can do lots of things before your code is actually compiled. Specifically, you could write a source file out that has your string and then use [`include_str!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) to bring it into your crate:

**build.rs**

```rust
use std::{
    env, error::Error, fs::File, io::{BufWriter, Write}, path::Path,
};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let out_dir = env::var("OUT_DIR")?;
    let dest_path = Path::new(&out_dir).join("long_string.txt");
    let mut f = BufWriter::new(File::create(&dest_path)?);

    let long_string = "abc".repeat(100);
    write!(f, "{}", long_string)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

**lib.rs**

```rust
static LONG_STRING: &'static str = include_str!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/long_string.txt"));
```

#### Lazy initialization

You could create a [once_cell](https://crates.io/crates/once_cell) or [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) value that would create your string at runtime, but only once.

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy; // 1.5.2

static LONG_STR: Lazy<String> = Lazy::new(|| "abc".repeat(5000));
```

See also:

- [How can you make a safe static singleton in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27221504/155423)
- [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423)

#### The far future

At some point, [RFC 911](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0911-const-fn.md) will be fully implemented. This, plus a handful of additional RFCs, each adding new functionality, will allow you to be able to write something like:

```rust
// Does not work yet!
static LONG_STR: String = "abc".repeat(1000);
```

Comment: There is [`str::repeat()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.str.html#method.repeat) now, so you can write `"abc".repeat(100)` to generate a `String` with your repeated data. A bit cleaner than the `iter::repeat()` version :)

Answer (score 17):

There are quite a few ways to do that.
You could load a pre-generated string from file if you like:

```
const DATA: &'static str = include_str!("filename.txt");
```

Or to do it during compilation you can use `concat!`:

```
const DATA: &'static str = concat!("abc", "abc");
```

Comment: Care to show an example for `concat!` that equates to `1000 * "abc"`? ^_^

Comment: I'm trying to create a "string multiplication" macro that uses `concat!` for 20 minutes now... sadly, I am heavily distracted and I haven't succeed yet :<  ... (yet!)

Comment: Here is my attempt: http://is.gd/fK8YIh
First macro I ever wrote in any language so no idea if any good.

Comment: @JohanLarsson The problem is, that OP wants a static string that is created at compile time. Your macro works, but does everything at runtime and returns a `String`...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the review, was just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 6):

Not proud of this answer :D but I wanted to to give a different perspective.

By using macro-rules, you can easily define static concatenation by composition. In this case, I define 100 * str = 4 * 25 * str = 4 * 5 * 5 * str. You could also do 100 * str = 10 * 10 * str, in less lines (but more columns :))

```rust
macro_rules! rep {
    ($t:expr, 4) => { concat!($t, $t, $t, $t) };
    ($t:expr, 5) => { concat!($t, $t, $t, $t, $t) };
    ($t:expr, 25) => { rep!(rep!($t, 5), 5) };
    ($t:expr, 100) => { rep!(rep!($t, 25), 4) };
}


fn main() {
    assert_eq!(rep!("x", 100).len(), 100);
}
```

Since macros work on language elements, it's not possible to use a counter and simple recursively call the macro like this:

```rust
macro_rules! does_not_work {
    ($t:expr, 1) => { $t };
    ($t:expr, $n:) => { concat!($t, does_not_work!($t, $n-1)) };
}
```

But recursively composing the macro should do the trick in this simple case. I didn't try using different macro_rules patterns or other kind of macros, but it should be possible to do something more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

There are crates that do that, e.g. [`const_format::str_repeat!()`](https://docs.rs/const_format/latest/const_format/macro.str_repeat.html).