# Can Rust macros create compile-time strings?

Tags: macros, rust

Macro variables are escaped in Rust macros by default. Is there any way to have them not escaped?

```
macro_rules! some {
    ( $var:expr ) => ( "$var" );
}

some!(1) // returns "$var", not "1"
```

This is useful for concatenating compile-time strings and such.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`stringify!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify!.html):

```
macro_rules! some {
    ( $var:expr ) => ( stringify!($var) );
}

fn main() {
    let s = some!(1);
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

And you will probably want [`concat!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat!.html) too.

See also:

- [How to create a static string at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32956050/155423)