# How do I generate a text file during compile time and include its content in the output?

Tags: build, rust, embedded-resource, rust-cargo, build-script

I'm trying to do almost the same as [How to create a static string at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956050/how-to-create-a-static-string-at-compile-time).

#### build.rs

```
use std::{env};
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::{Write, BufWriter};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let out_dir = env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
    let dest_path = Path::new(&out_dir).join("file_path.txt");
    let mut f = BufWriter::new(File::create(&dest_path).unwrap());

    let long_string = dest_path.display();
    write!(f, "{}", long_string).unwrap();
}
```

#### main.rs

```
fn main() {

    static LONG_STRING: &'static str = include_str!("file_path.txt");
    println!("{}", LONG_STRING);
}
```

Upon `cargo build` I'm getting the error:

```
error: couldn't read src\file_path.txt: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
 --> src\main.rs:3:40
  |
3 |     static LONG_STRING: &'static str = include_str!("file_path.txt");
  |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I can see that the file is generated at

```
X:\source\github\rust-build-script-example\target\debug\build\rust-build-script-example-f2a03ef7abfd6b23\out\file_path.txt
```

1. What is the environment variable I have to use instead of OUT_DIR in order to get the `file_path.txt` to be output to the `src` directory?
2. If #1 is not possible, then how do I `include_str!` the generated file in the above directory without hardcoding it in code (since the path seems to have a randomly generated partial `rust-build-script-example-f2a03ef7abfd6b23` in it)

[My GitHub repository](https://github.com/harindaka/rust-build-script-example/tree/7b212769d628d149389482be05551004f6b03a06)

Answer (score 12):

The trick was

```
concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/file_path.txt")
```

I changed my main.rs as follows and it worked.

```
fn main() {

    static LONG_STRING: &'static str = include_str!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/file_path.txt"));

    println!("{}", LONG_STRING);
}
```

The following crates.io documentation helped

http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested in a more convenient way to achieve the same, I also created the [build_script_file_gen crate](https://crates.io/crates/build_script_file_gen) which can be used as follows

#### build.rs

```
extern crate build_script_file_gen;
use build_script_file_gen::gen_file_str;

fn main() {
    let file_content = "Hello World!";
    gen_file_str("hello.txt", &file_content);
}
```

#### main.rs

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate build_script_file_gen;

fn main() {
    println!(include_file_str!("hello.txt"));
}
```