# How to specify a floating point number literal using hexadecimal notation In Rust?

Tags: rust, floating-point, hex, unsigned-integer

I'm implementing [xoshiro256++](http://prng.di.unimi.it) and I'm able to generate pseudo-random 64-bit unsigned integers. The next challenge is generating uniform doubles in the unit interval from the PRNGs u64's.

> a 64-bit unsigned integer x should be converted to a 64-bit double using the expression
>
> ```
> (x >> 11) * 0x1.0p-53
> ```

How would one evaluate this in Rust? On trying this I get the compile error:

```
error: hexadecimal float literal is not supported
  --> src/main.rs:30:56
   |
30 |             f64::from_bits((x >> 11).wrapping_mul(0x1.0p-53))
   |                                                        ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [hexf crate](https://crates.io/crates/hexf):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate hexf;

fn main() {
    let v = hexf64!("0x1.0p-53");
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

See also:

- [How to create a static string at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32956050/155423)

Comment: Is there a way to use std only? trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: @ANoobSwiftly how would using std only help you understand what's going on? But sure, just copy all of the source code from the crate and whatever dependencies into your own code. Now you have no extra crates.

Comment: Would this behave the same as their implementation: ((x >> 11) as f64) * (f64::exp2(-53.0))?