# How do I parse a string with a C++ style hex float (%a) to a f64?

Tags: serialization, rust, floating-point, hex

I need to parse a text file with bunch of float numbers that were created via C++'s `printf("%a")` and looks like:

```
-0x1.68p+6 -0x1.68p+7
```

As I understand it, this is the mantissa and exponent in hex.

Is there any way to parse this with the standard library? I could not find a `f64::from_str_radix`, and even if it existed,
would it parse the `0x` and `p` parts correctly?

I suppose I missed something, because the lossless conversion of `f64` <-> `String` should be popular enough
functions to include them into standard library.

Comment: See also [How to specify a floating point number literal using hexadecimal notation In Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63488332/155423).

Comment: Re: "the lossless conversion of `f64` <-> `String` should be popular enough functions to include them into standard library" - You're right! The default `Debug` formatter (what you get by formatting with `{:?}`) is lossless. So is `f64::to_bits`, come to think of it. Neither of those is the format you're trying to parse, though.

Comment: "this is the mantissa and exponent in hex." --> not quite.  The `-0x1.68` is the significand in hex and the exponent `+6` is the decimal power of 2.