# How can I move structs containing Vec to/from a static array without getting E0507?

Tags: rust, move

I need a static array of structs and the structs contain a Vec. I can manage the lifetimes of the actual values. I get the following error:

```
: Mar23 ; cargo test
Compiling smalltalk v0.1.0 (/Users/dmason/git/AST-Smalltalk/rust)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `dispatchTable[_]` as `dispatchTable` is a static item
  --> src/minimal.rs:32:44
   |
30 |         let old = ManuallyDrop::into_inner(dispatchTable[pos]);
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `dispatchTable[_]` has type `ManuallyDrop<Option<Box<Dispatch>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Here is a minimal compilable example:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct MethodMatch {
    hash: i64,
    method: Option<bool>,
}
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Dispatch {
    class: i64,
    table: Vec<MethodMatch>,
}

const max_classes : usize = 100;
use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;
const no_dispatch : ManuallyDrop<Option<Box<Dispatch>>> = ManuallyDrop::new(None);
static mut dispatchTable : [ManuallyDrop<Option<Box<Dispatch>>>;max_classes] = [no_dispatch;max_classes];
use std::sync::RwLock;
lazy_static! {
    static ref dispatchFree : RwLock<usize> = {RwLock::new(0)};
}
pub fn addClass(c : i64, n : usize) {
    let mut index = dispatchFree.write().unwrap();
    let pos = *index;
    *index += 1;
    replaceDispatch(pos,c,n);
}
pub fn replaceDispatch(pos : usize, c : i64, n : usize) -> Option<Box<Dispatch>> {
    let mut table = Vec::with_capacity(n);
    table.resize(n,MethodMatch{hash:0,method:None});
    unsafe {
        let old = ManuallyDrop::into_inner(dispatchTable[pos]);
        dispatchTable[pos]=ManuallyDrop::new(Some(Box::new(Dispatch{class:c,table:table})));
        old
    }
}
```

The idea I had was to have `replaceDispatch` create a new Dispatch option object, and replace the current value in the array with the new one, returning the original, with the idea that the caller will get the Dispatch option value and be able to use and then drop/deallocate the object.

I found that it will compile if I add `.clone()` right after the identified error point. **But** then the original value never gets dropped, so (the into_inner is redundant and) *I'm creating a memory leak*!. Do I have to manually drop it (if I could figure out how)? I thought that's what `ManuallyDrop` bought me. In theory, if I created a copy of the fields from the Vec into a copy, that would point to the old data, so when that object got dropped, the memory would get freed. But (a) that seems very dirty, (b) it's a bit of ugly, unnecessary code (I have to handle the Some/None cases, look inside the Vec, etc.), and (c) I can't see how I'd even do it!!!!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about your problem, but there should rarely if ever be any reason to put a `ManuallyDrop` in a `static` since statics never get dropped anyway.

Comment: @trentcl `ManuallyDrop` allows the OP to initialize the array with `None` because `ManuallyDrop<Option<T>>` is apparently `Copy`, while `Option<T>` is not. Assigning `Default::default()` to `dispatchTable` won't work either because max_classes exceeds 32.

Comment: @user4815162342 It's not `ManuallyDrop` that allows the OP to initialize the array; it's because of `const no_dispatch`. [No `ManuallyDrop`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9554edc5ea2c484b2a4d49320fe849b4)

Comment: BTW, `static mut` is very difficult to use correctly and wrap in a safe API. It's enough of a footgun that [eventual deprecation isn't out of the question](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53639). What you should normally do instead is use a regular `static` with interior mutability such as `Mutex<T>`, `AtomicT` or `UnsafeCell<T>`. `UnsafeCell` is both the most versatile and the most annoying to put in a `static` (because it's not `Sync`), but [`AtomicPtr` isn't too bad](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3583debe55b7fbef0842492613384628).

Comment: @trentcl That's great, and relevant to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28656387/1600898) which I've now added an answer to. Existing answers led me to 
 conclude that `ManuallyDrop` is somehow the secret sauce behind how the OP managed to initialize the array. I guess the version with the `const` works because the const is replaced with the actual value on every use so it doesn't need to be `Copy`, but it's not at all obvious that it is guaranteed to work (except through the stability guarantees).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll seriously think about one of those alternatives. Unfortunately the array reference (not the update) is on a critical path, so any locking is a potential issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler tells you, you cannot move a value out of a place observable by others. But since you have the replacement at the ready, you can use `std::mem::replace`:

```
pub fn replaceDispatch(pos: usize, c: i64, n: usize) -> Option<Box<Dispatch>> {
    ... table handling omitted ...
    unsafe {
        let old = std::mem::replace(
            &mut dispatchTable[pos],
            ManuallyDrop::new(Some(Box::new(Dispatch {
                class: c,
                table: table,
            }))),
        );
        ManuallyDrop::into_inner(old)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cbb5933febe23d4c8768c226f25c530a)

In fact, since you're using the `Option` to manage the lifetime of `Dispatch`, you don't need `ManuallyDrop` at all, and you also don't need the `Box`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e1553f47ad403282c9193e84a536148f).

Comment: Perfect! I knew there had to be a clean way to do it. And `std::mem::replace` isn't even unsafe (because a value is consumed and another value is returned to be dropped). It's the reference to the `mut static` that is unsafe, which I already know about and will protect against (this update is actually rare)

Comment: @DaveMason Also note that you (at least in this example) don't need either the `Box` or indeed `ManuallyDrop` - see the playground linked from the updated answer.