# How to create an array of more than 32 elements of a generic type T: Default?

Tags: arrays, rust, unsafe

This question is similar to [Initialize a large, fixed-size array with non-Copy types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656387/initialize-a-large-fixed-size-array-with-non-copy-types/40996035) but for an array of a generic type.

I have this struct:

```rust
struct Foo<T>([T; 99]);
```

If `T` implements `Default`, how do I write an implementation of `Default` for `Foo<T>`?

```rust
impl<T: Default> Default for Foo<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        // ???
    }
}
```

The naive approach does not work because `Default` is only implemented for arrays up to length 32:

```rust
Foo(Default::default())
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[_; 99]: Default` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:5:13
  |
5 |         Foo(Default::default())
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Default` is not implemented for `[_; 99]`
  |
```

This works (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28666474/14637)), but uses a deprecated function:

```rust
Foo(unsafe {
    let mut arr: [T; 99] = std::mem::uninitialized();
    for e in &mut arr {
        std::ptr::write(e, T::default());
    }
    arr
})
```

```
warning: use of deprecated function `std::mem::uninitialized`: use `mem::MaybeUninit` instead
 --> src/lib.rs:6:36
  |
6 |             let mut arr: [T; 99] = std::mem::uninitialized();
  |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
```

I tried to use the new and shiny `MaybeUninit`, following [an example in its docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-an-array-element-by-element):

```rust
Foo(unsafe {
    use std::mem::MaybeUninit;
    let mut arr: [MaybeUninit<T>; 99] = {
        MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()
    };
    for e in &mut arr {
        *e = MaybeUninit::new(T::default());
    }
    std::mem::transmute(arr)
})
```

```
error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:13
   |
13 |             std::mem::transmute(arr)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: `[MaybeUninit<T>; 99]` (size can vary because of T)
   = note: target type: `[T; 99]` (size can vary because of T)
```

It's guaranteed that `MaybeUninit<T>` has the same size as `T`, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the same holds for `[MaybeUninit<T>; 99]` and `[T; 99]`, as per the docs:

> However remember that a type *containing* a `MaybeUninit<T>` is not necessarily the same layout; Rust does not in general guarantee that the fields of a `Foo<T>` have the same order as a `Foo<U>` even if `T` and `U` have the same size and alignment.

I'm not sure this sentence applies to arrays, but it seems the compiler isn't sure either.

How can I write this function without using the deprecated `std::mem::uninitialized()`? Note that I'm using a raw array specifically to avoid allocations, so the solution should be allocation-free as well.

For your convenience, here's a [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cd25f30e1f10cca53d191e14cf93e05a).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the deprecated `std::mem::uninitialized()` function by following the recipe from [`MaybeUninit` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-an-array-element-by-element).

As you discovered, you'll need to switch from the scary `transmute` to the even scarier `transmute_copy` due to (what's likely) a [compiler issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61956). In this case `transmute_copy()` is sound because you're transmuting `MaybeUninit`s (which are not dropped) and which you're not touching after the transmute.

```
impl<T: Default> Default for Foo<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Foo(unsafe {
            // `assume_init` is sound here because the type we are claiming to have
            // initialized consists of `MaybeUninit`s, which do not require initialization.
            let mut arr: [MaybeUninit<T>; 99] = MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init();
            for e in &mut arr {
                *e = MaybeUninit::new(T::default());
            }
            // transmute_copy required due to a (likely) compiler bug,
            // see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62875
            std::mem::transmute_copy(&arr)
        })
    }
}
```

> It's guaranteed that `MaybeUninit<T>` has the same size as `T`, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the same holds for `[MaybeUninit<T>; 99]` and `[T; 99]`, as per the docs: "However remember that a type containing a `MaybeUninit<T>` is not necessarily the same layout [...]"

The docs are correct to warn about containers in general because of (among other things) niche optimizations; the size of `Option<usize>` and `Option<&u8>` are different even though the sizes of `usize` and `&u8` are equal.

The array initialization example from the `MaybeUninit` docs is a pretty strong indication that the warning doesn't apply to arrays. Even if you don't accept the doc example as a chapter-and-verse *guarantee*, keep in mind that that code has been in the docs for years now, and there is a lot of code that makes use of it (I [wrote some](https://github.com/Kromey/serde_arrays/pull/1) just a couple of weeks ago and [found more](https://github.com/est31/serde-big-array/blob/261b4796f1cb847ed7b46e38f01bdede09ada6d7/src/const_generics.rs#L62)). Not only would it all break if the guarantee went away, but there would be no way to initialize an array element by element.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I guess `transmute_copy` always incurs a (raw, bit-for-bit) copy though, which would break return value optimization. From that point of view, I think just using `std::mem::uninitialized()` and suppressing the deprecation warning might be a more efficient (and also shorter and more readable) option. But this is as good an answer as the current Rust version allows, so I'll accept it.

Comment: There is a tracking issue for `MaybeUninit::array_assume_init` which would help here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80908

Comment: @Thomas It's an interesting question whether `std::mem::uninitialized()` is a better choice here. As I understand it, creating an uninitialized `[T; 99]` (as opposed to `[MaybeUninit<T>; 99]`) is undefined behavior, plain and simple, so I'd avoid it just for that. The code in the docs (and hopefully in this answer) has no undefined behavior, and might well compile to the same assembly as the original version - but that is best verified with godbolt.

Comment: @Thomas `transmute_copy()` is just a fancy way of spelling `std::ptr::read()`; I don't think it's required to do any actual copying. Despite the unsafety, the memory model still applies, and the compiler should be free to optimize such things away, just like taking a reference to a value doesn't necessarily prevent the value from being stored in a register. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/xK66Kxs4Y) is an example where calling `transmute_copy()` doesn't result in an additional copy being made compared to an ordinary move.

Comment: @Thomas Even more impressively, [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/Y645xsrsT) shows rust/LLVM able to compile the whole `MaybeUninit` ceremony into _identical code_ as the one generated by a simple move!