# How to initialize [Option<Box<T>>; N] with None?

Tags: rust

I now why the error below happens, you cannot copy a Box, because it's a "unique_ptr".

```
fn main() {
    let array: [Option<Box<u32>>; 3] = [None; 3];
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0da6902c0157df3015bc85a621079e18

I know I could do `[None, None, None]`, but what about giant arrays? Is there a way to initialize them with None?

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Option<Box<u32>>: Copy` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:2:40
  |
2 |     let array: [Option<Box<u32>>; 3] = [None; 3];
  |                                        ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Copy` is not implemented for `Option<Box<u32>>`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <Option<T> as Copy>
  = note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied
```

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28656387/1600898) resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

For arrays with a size not greater than 32 you could use:
`let array: [Option<Box<u32>>; 32] = Default::default();`

For even bigger arrays I would recommend using a crate like [this](https://github.com/Manishearth/array-init) or creating a simple `macro`.

I recommend reading this article: https://www.joshmcguigan.com/blog/array-initialization-rust/