# Array of vectors of tuples in rust?

Tags: rust

I need a weighted adjacency list in rust, how would I initiate that? In C++ it would look something like this:

```cpp
const int SZ = 100;
vector<pair<int, int>> adj[MM];
```

Here's what I tried in rust so far:

```rust
const MM: usize = 100;
let mut adj: [Vec<(i32, i32)>; MM] = // what goes here?
```

Comment: Might I suggest some structs in there? Nesting built-in types arbitrarily deeply is a great way to ensure that nobody (yourself included, six months from now) will understand the intent of your data structures.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'm new to rust, so do you mind posting an example as an answer?

Comment: For future reference, this type of ds can be initialized similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69756635/14277568)

Comment: Ideally you'd use `Default::default()` (like C++ does implicitly), but that doesn't work for [boring technical reasons](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61415). In addition to the plethora of solutions provided in the linked question, a stupid and simple approach is to use `vec![...; MM]` and then convert that to array using `.try_into().unwrap()`. In other words, you can use `let mud adj: [Vec<(i32, i32)>; MM] = vec![vec![]; MM].try_into().unwrap();`.

Comment: I made an actual answer out of it as you guys seem to already have come to a conclusion here, and having the answer in the comment section is not in the spirit of stackoverflow.

Comment: @Finomnis This is a duplicate, and all those answers already appear in the duplicate. You should vote to close, not answer.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Why not both?

Comment: @Finomnis Because the very reason we close duplicates is to prevent pollution of the site.

Comment: Yes, that's why I also think closing is a good idea. That doesn't prevent me from answering more explicitly though

Comment: @Finomnis Then you keep adding to the site pollution and make it hard to find good resources. The community really dislikes this. [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367892/) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315936) [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution)

Comment: Got it. Makes sense. "encourages low quality questions instead of doing prior research yourself" was what resonated with me.

Answer (score 1):

```rust
fn main() {
    const MM: usize = 100;
    let adj: [Vec<(i32, i32)>; MM] = [(); MM].map(|()| vec![]);

    println!("{:?}", adj);
}
```

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```