# How to initialize a Option<T> array in rust?

Tags: rust, rust-no-std

So I'm trying to implement a simple queue for a no_std environment with no heap allocations like this:

```rust
pub struct Queue<T: Sized, const SIZE: usize> {
    pub data: [Option<T>; SIZE],
}

impl<T: Sized, const SIZE: usize> Queue<T, SIZE> {
    pub const fn new() -> Queue<T, SIZE> {
        const DEFAULT: Option<T> = None;
        Queue {
            data: [DEFAULT; SIZE],
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me that this should be possible since T is sized and a `None` value can be `const` so it can be copied without T having to implement the `Copy` trait.
I cannot seem to figure out how to do it however.
The above syntax gives an error with a wonderfully useless tip suggesting I should replace `T` with `T`:

```
error[E0401]: can't use generic parameters from outer function
  --> src/queue.rs:11:31
   |
9  | impl<T: Sized, const SIZE: usize> Queue<T, SIZE> {
   |      - type parameter from outer function
10 |     pub const fn new() -> Queue<T, SIZE> {
11 |         const DEFAULT: Option<T> = Default::default();
   |                      -        ^ use of generic parameter from outer function
   |                      |
   |                      help: try using a local generic parameter instead: `<T>`
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm using the 2021 edition of rust by the way.

Comment: "The above syntax gives a wonderfully useless error suggesting I should replace T with T" My understanding is that this isn't what the error is saying, but that you cannot use the generic parameter from the outer scope within the function. It seems consistent with [the document of error E0401](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0401.html).

Comment: @VincentSavard You're right, the error is pretty clear, I just meant the hint is not worded very clearly.

Comment: For the bad hint: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/78789

Comment: This question was at one point closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656387/initialize-a-large-fixed-size-array-with-non-copy-types but none of the answers there fit this situation where the array is to be created in a `const fn`. May I suggest that you edit your title/introduction to be clear that this is for a `const` context specifically?

Comment: @KevinReid [inline const does work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=acb939c55ba5b4c60d684358fc051aef) and is [suggested in the dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74932052/442760)

Comment: @cafce25 It's an unstable feature, and thus not fit as a general-purpose solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associated constants of a type are allowed to use its parameters, so this compiles:

```rust
pub struct Queue<T: Sized, const SIZE: usize> {
    pub data: [Option<T>; SIZE],
}

impl<T: Sized, const SIZE: usize> Queue<T, SIZE> {
    const NONE_T: Option<T> = None;

    pub const fn new() -> Queue<T, SIZE> {
        Queue {
            data: [Self::NONE_T; SIZE],
        }
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f93292b4e67e90ed280e1e5132c1134a))

It's unfortunate that the constant can't be inside the function, but it can at least be private.

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for! I would prefer to have the constant in the function of course, but I'm already happy that I don't have to force all my structs to implement `Copy`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using nightly, you can enable the `inline_const` feature and not even require a const item:

```rust
#![feature(inline_const)]

pub struct Queue<T: Sized, const SIZE: usize> {
    pub data: [Option<T>; SIZE],
}

impl<T: Sized, const SIZE: usize> Queue<T, SIZE> {
    pub const fn new() -> Queue<T, SIZE> {
        Queue {
            data: [const { None }; SIZE],
        }
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6dcf2e9b6885457533244aca0daf2e36))