# How do I initialize a slice of HashMaps?

Tags: rust

I have a situation where I want a slice of HashMaps, with the length of the slice specified by a constant. How can I initialize such a beast?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::default::Default;

const LENGTH: usize = 10;

fn main() {
    let f: [HashMap<String, u32>; LENGTH] = ???;
}
```

I've tried several versions of things in the ??? spot:

```
Default::default()
[HashMap::new(); LENGTH]
[Default::default(); LENGTH]
iter::repeat(HashMap::new()).take(LENGTH).collect().as_slice()
```

Each one gives me different errors:

```
test.rs:7:45: 7:61 error: the trait `core::default::Default` is not implemented for the type `[std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<collections::string::String, u32>; 10]` [E0277]
test.rs:7     let f: [HashMap<String, u32>; LENGTH] = Default::default();
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

test.rs:7:45: 7:69 error: the trait `core::marker::Copy` is not implemented for the type `std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<collections::string::String, u32>` [E0277]
test.rs:7     let f: [HashMap<String, u32>; LENGTH] = [HashMap::new(); LENGTH];
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

test.rs:7:45: 7:73 error: the trait `core::marker::Copy` is not implemented for the type `std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<collections::string::String, u32>` [E0277]
test.rs:7     let f: [HashMap<String, u32>; LENGTH] = [Default::default(); LENGTH];
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

test.rs:8:45: 8:107 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
test.rs:8     let f: [HashMap<String, u32>; LENGTH] = iter::repeat(HashMap::new()).take(LENGTH).collect().as_slice();
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there some special magic that I'm missing here? Or am I hitting a bug?

Comment: `[type; length]` isn't a *slice* - it's an *array*. Arrays have a known fixed size at compile time. Slices only have a known length at run time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I initialize an array of vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393166/how-do-i-initialize-an-array-of-vectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a slice, but a fixed-size array.

You can't create a slice with some content, because slice is only a "view" into a memory that belongs to something else (like an array or a vector).

Fixed-size arrays in Rust < 1.52 are generally useless. That's because Rust doesn't support generic types with integer arguments yet, but almost all things in Rust are implemented as traits (generics), so they don't work for arrays.

You'll need to use a `Vec`.

Comment: Const generics will save us soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `MaybeUninit` is the best way I can think of. Exactly the same thing is in its docs: [initializing-an-array-element-by-element](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-an-array-element-by-element).

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e99e14cfe855d4bba31f672faa25ddb7)

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::mem::{MaybeUninit, transmute};

const LENGTH: usize = 10;

fn main() {
    let _data: [HashMap<String, u32>; LENGTH] = {
        let mut data: [MaybeUninit<HashMap<String, u32>>; LENGTH] = unsafe {
            MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()
        };

        for elem in &mut data[..] {
            *elem = MaybeUninit::new(HashMap::new());
        }

        unsafe { transmute::<_, [HashMap<String, u32>; LENGTH]>(data) }
    };
}
```